# Json get contents using 2 foreach in php to retrieve multiple nodes depth

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5, command

I have a json file and Im trying to include the information into a Mysql DB table. Json file:

```
"categories": [{
            "id": "cat0101000",
            "name": "TVs",
            "url": "https://www.url.com/site/",
            "path": [
                {
                    "name": "Home",
                    "id": "cat00000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TV & Home Theater",
                    "id": "cat0100000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TVs",
                    "id": "cat0101000"
                }
            ],
```

The code to include each registry:

```
public function handle()
{
    $json = file_get_contents('resources/json/categories_0001.json');
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $array1 = (array)$data;
    foreach ($array1['categories'] as $obj) {
        DB::table('categories')->insert(array(
            'categoryId' => ((isset($obj->id) ? $obj->id : 1)),
            'categoryName' => ((isset($obj->name) ? $obj->name : null)),
            'parentId' => end($obj->path)->id,
            'URL' => ((isset($obj->url) ? $obj->url : 1)),
        ));
    }
}
```

My idea is to include all records inside "path" concatenating all fields. eg:

> 'path' => . "$obj->path->id" . "\" . "$obj->path->id" . "\" .
>   "$obj->path->id"

I tried foreach inside foreach but with no success. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changed object to array and trying to get like object change this

```
 $array1 = (array)$data;
  foreach ($array1['categories'] as $obj) {
```

To

```
 foreach ($data->categories as $obj) {
```

Comment: my problem is that Im using DB::table('categories')->insert(array( and I cannot find the way to include a foreach inside that statement (->insert)

Comment: You can make array first and then put inside insert